# C++ loading numbers from a file then finding the sum

Tags: c++, arrays, sum, average, mean

I posted something on this last night, but I have decided to change my approach slightly as I wasn't fully understanding the code I was trying to use.

I apologise as I know this topic has been done to death but I'd like a little help with the code I've written.

I'm loading a .txt file from my computer with 100 integers in. They are each on new lines.

This is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    ifstream fout;
    ifstream fin;



    string line;
    ifstream myfile ("100intergers.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while ( getline(myfile,line) )
        {
            cout << line << '\n';
        }

        // Closes my file
        myfile.close();


        // If my file is still open, then show closing error
    if (myfile.is_open())
        cerr << "Error closing file" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }


    int y = 0;
    int z = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    double avg = 0.0;

    avg = sum/(y+z);
    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "sum = " << sum << endl;
    cout << "average = " << avg << endl;

    // checking for error
    if (!myfile.eof())
    {
        cerr << "Error reading file" << endl;
        exit(2);
    }

    // close file stream "myfile"
    myfile.close();

    return(0);

}
```

When I run it I get exit code 1 (as well as a list of my 100 integers).

Which means my if clause isn't the right choice, what's a better alternative?

If I delete that bit completely, it fails to run do to an arithmetic error which I think is 0/0*0

Also I think the code I've written for the .txt file is for words, not numbers, but when I change string to int it really bugs and tells me I have more problems than without.

Finally - after this I want to make an array to calc variance - any tips?

Cheers

Jack

Comment: Did you want to actually sum the integers in the file? As is, you're just dividing by zero...

Comment: To calc variance, you only need to store the summation of `n^2`. There is no need to store everything.

Comment: in the .txt file? no, it's just a list like: 
1
2 etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're reading lines from the file, which you output.

Then you do arithmetic with some variables, all of which have the value zero.
These variables have no connection to the file's contents.

I'll help with the basic loop structure by showing a way to count the numbers in the file:

```
int main()
{
    int value = 0;
    int count = 0;
    ifstream myfile("100intergers.txt");
    while (myfile >> value)
    {
        count++;
    }
    cout << "There were " << count << " numbers." << endl;
}
```

Summing and the rest is left as an exercise.

Comment: Thank you - I tried to load my new code but I'm terrible at mini markdown.
The number of the integers is important as it will help me find the mean, however summing the numbers is q difficult as I started C++ yesterday.

Is there a good way for the language to know the values in the text?

Thank you again

Comment: @Jack You need another variable (similar to `count`). It will probably called `sum`. Then, instead of adding 1 to it, you add each number to it inside the loop. That's all you need.